# Stuck in either a headless state or at the start of the branch in git

Tags: git, version-control, github

First off, I'm sorry if this is stupid but I'm not very comfortable yet with git (I usually use mercurial for my source control).

I've got a git repository (https://github.com/jordanwallwork/jello if it helps anyone) where I have two branches; master and develop. The plan was to code on develop and then merge stable code into master when it was in a fit state. That all seemed to be going ok until I had to pull the repo on another machine. Now I've pulled it I'm having trouble getting to my current position on the develop branch.

When I try run `git checkout develop` it puts me at the very start, where I originally branched off of master. After some messing around I found that I could get to the current state by running `git checkout remotes/origin/develop` - this does give me the files I need, but it puts me in a 'headless' state and I can no longer simply push as I used to do (I have to run `git push origin HEAD:develop`). (This also made me think I could try something like `git checkout HEAD:develop` but that wasn't valid!)

Please can anyone help me get back onto my branch! If you can explain where I went wrong too that'd be brilliant. I'm concerned that I branched wrong in the first place but can't remember what command I actually ran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial and git actually do pretty much the same thing with *revisions* here; what's different, and causing you grief, is the way items are labeled.

In Mercurial a branch is a very permanent and persistent entity.  Not so much in terms of revisions, but rather because each commit is recorded as being *on* some particular branch, regardless of any internal commit-graph.  Within an hg branch it's possible to have multiple "heads":

```
     C   [one "head" on branch develop]
    /
A--B
    \
     D   [another "head", also still on branch develop]
```

In Mercurial you can't name one or the other head by talking about the branch, as "branch develop" has both heads.  (You can create bookmarks for revisions `C` and `D`, or refer to them by number, `-r 1131` or whatever.)

This particular situation can't<sup>1</sup> occur in git as it insists on having *different* names for the two heads:

```
     C   <-- develop
    /
A--B
    \
     D   <-- (some other name: can't be "develop", that one is taken!)
```

It can get away with this because branch names are *not* permanent and persistent; commits don't record their branch, so at any time you can just rename `develop` to `develop2` and add another different `develop` somewhere else.  This is very flexible and can lead you into all kinds of trouble. :-)  If used carefully it's pretty nice (I prefer it to hg heads, where you have to start adding bookmarks to keep track, and in my experience the bookmarks don't "travel" very well).

Because git doesn't have permanent-and-persistent branch names, but *does* have the same distributed aspect as hg, the git system has to tackle the problem that the tip of some actively-developed branch gets out of sync on different repositories.  While you're working on your copy, in your `develop`, someone else—maybe even you—clones the same original repo and works on his (different) `develop`.  In hg, if you both pushed, you'd just create multiple heads.  (Sometimes you really do want to do this: someone, maybe you, will resolve them later, but meanwhile everyone needs to be able to *see* them.)  In git, to achieve the same thing, you need to arrange to use different branch-names *on the shared remote*.

To achieve this, git renames *everything* on the remote vs the local repository.  Typically "the" (single) remote is named `origin`.  You `git clone` some URL, which sets that up as `origin`, and then `pull` and `push` with that.  Meanwhile git copies all the branches it finds on `origin` over to your local repo, but calls them `origin/name` (e.g., `origin/master` and `origin/develop`) to keep them separate from your own local branch names.<sup>2</sup>

Just to confuse everyone :-) the best equivalent of `hg pull` is actually `git fetch`.  The command `git pull` really runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, if you tell it to, `git rebase` instead).  (Curiously, `hg` also has a [deprecated] `fetch` command, which does a pull-update-and-merge, which means `hg fetch` is the equivalent of `git pull`!)

The `git fetch` command goes over to the remote (you can name the particular remote, `git fetch origin`, but with just one remote there's no need) and brings over any new commits, and updates your repo with labels for "what's the latest over on `origin`".  In particular, it will update your "what was over there the last time I checked" value, stored in `origin/develop` in this case (as well as `origin/master` and any other branches it finds).

Once you are re-synched, you can then run a separate `git merge` or `git rebase` to update *your* branch named `develop`, based on *their* branch named `develop`, which in your repo is renamed to `origin/develop`.<sup>3</sup>  For instance:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only origin/develop
```

The `--ff-only` tells merge to move the label only if you have no changes of your own that would require a real merge.  (Leave it out if you want git to just do a merge, of course.)

The `git pull` command *should* be (and soon *will* be, with git 1.9) just a convenient shortcut that does the appropriate `git fetch` followed by the appropriate `git merge` (or, again, `git rebase`, if you pull with `--rebase` or set up auto-rebasing).  But right now, in git 1.8 and earlier, if/when you `git pull origin develop`, git brings over the new revisions and merges-or-rebases your current branch, *but does not update* `origin/develop`.  This is inconsistent with `git push`: when you `push` your changes back, that *does* update `origin/develop`.  It's annoying, and at least slightly broken, hence the upcoming change.

(Mercurial gets away without any of this fancy naming because of its anonymous heads.  The problem never occurs in the first place.)

The "TL;DR" version of all this is: I recommend using the two-step sequence, `git fetch` followed by a manual `git merge` or `git rebase`, at least until git 1.9 comes out.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you can and do get unnamed commits and branches in git.  Commits that are not reachable by a label are "dangling", in `git fsck` terminology, or "abandoned" in mine—although I make a technical distinction here: an "abandoned" branch is normally still kept in git's "reflog" and persists in the repository until the reflog entries expire.  A "dangling" branch has not even a reflog reference, and is collected and discarded on the next `git gc`.

<sup>2</sup>The "full name" of a (local) branch is `refs/heads/name`.  The full name of a remote branch includes both the name of the remote *and* the name of the branch: `refs/heads/remote/name`.  The `heads` part distinguishes these from other kinds of references: tags, for instance, live in the `refs/tags/name` space.  Technically speaking, this particular bit of planning-ahead works brilliantly: new name-spaces can be invented "after the fact" without colliding with existing names.  For instance, git's "notes" use `refs/notes/`, and the stash uses `refs/stash`, all with no changes to the internal git machinery.

<sup>3</sup>If you set up local branch `develop` as "tracking" remote-branch `origin/develop`, and set up several other configuration items, git's use of the local and remote names works as well and as conveniently as Mercurial's single global branch-name-space.  In other words, it only takes a modest amount of extra work that no beginner would know about, and an upgrade to git 1.9, to get git to work as well for a beginner as Mercurial does. :-)  This should mostly be defaulted correctly in git 2.0.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thanks for taking the time, that really cleared a whole bunch of stuff up for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Aha I've done it!  All it took was: `git pull origin develop`

I didn't realise that you had to pull the branch after checking it out (since the files were already on my machine + I could see them in the branch history)

Comment: Although this will do the trick, it's not the method I prefer, because it currently leaves `origin/develop` un-updated.  I'll put more in an actual answer.